# Incompatibilidade de Código Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Estou usando um script para alternar um bloco com Nav Tabs, a primeira parte do código funciona normalmente, porém a parte onde faço a requisição da border-color e jogo para o outro campo só está funcionando no Chrome, alguém saberia me dizer porque?

JS:

```
            $(function(){
            $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).tab('show');
                var corbackground = $('#myTab>.active>a').css('border-color');
                $('.tab-content').css('border-color',corbackground);
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#peito">Peito</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#biceps">Biceps</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#costa">Costa</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#triceps">Triceps</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="peito">
                                         <a href="#idphp" class="exercicio" title=""></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane" id="biceps">2</div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane" id="costa">3</div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane" id="triceps">4</div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Sem ver o HTML fica um pouco difícil, mas pela lógica não deveria pegar o border-color do $(this) que foi clicado?

Comment: Exato, é o mesmo elemento do this, porém mesmo assim não funcionava, então tentei criar o seletor novamente pra ver se resolvia e também nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um pequeno bug com o IE e o Firefox, e para obter a cor da borda deve pedir por `border-top-color`, como no ex. abaixo:

**jquery:**

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tab-pane').not($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    $('.tab-content').css('border-color', $(this).css('border-top-color'));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/7s01p1z0/)